# Replace all the color of each pixel using PIL (currently replacing specific color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to replace a color range with some specific color using PIL module.
Suppose I want to change the color of the sky,I need to generate a list of the color of pixels.

[image]

My code currently

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor

im = Image.open("iphone.jpg", "r")
to_be_replaced = ImageColor.getcolor("#5f86c9", "RGB")
newcolor = ImageColor.getcolor("#c9bb5f", "RGB")
print(to_be_replaced, newcolor)

pix = im.load()
width, height = im.size
for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        r, g, b = pix[(w, h)]
        if (r, g, b) == to_be_replaced:
            pix[w, h] = newcolor
        else:
            pix[w, h] = (r, g, b)
im.save('test.png', 'PNG')
```

`newcolor` here is the yellow color, and `to_be_replaced` is the color of a pixel from the sky.

Code output till now:
[image]
The script works, but currently, it changes the color of just a pixel with the specified color. I want to replace the color of the whole sky. Can anybody please help me with this problem?

Comment: You are changing a specific color value. If you want to change the color of the sky you would need to determine the window range of values you would want to replace. You could try segmentation on a single color spectrum to get the mask of the sky. I am assuming you only want to color the blue sky.

Comment: @JasonChia Yes I want to replace the blue color. I'm pretty new to this so can you guide me through "segmentation on a single color spectrum"?

Comment: You have RGB color in your image. For this particular problem you want to only replace BLUE. Simply find all pixels where the B value is significantly greater  than R and G and it should work well enough (will fail if there is blue elsewhere). if you want more complex methods: a quick google search for sky segmentation and you'll find many papers on various approaches and algorithms.

Comment: Not sure if using array (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155749/replace-elements-in-numpy-array-avoiding-loops) is faster or not ? You should check it

Comment: Better example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value